# Is it possible to set a variable for a stored procedure as column type?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

It seems like a simple enough event you just declare a variable you are passing to your stored procedure as column. I am needing to pass a column name to my stored procedure that will be used in my query. Is it possible to declare it so I can use it as a column name or is there some way I can convert say a string to column type?

```
where Line1AStatus = 1
```

I need to be able to pass to my stored procedure what that number is in Line Status. I have tried these methods so far. Thank you for your help.

```
where Line + @LineNum + AStatus = 1
where 'Line' + @LinNum + 'AStatus' = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not with standard SQL but you can with dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM table where ''Line' + CAST(@LinNum AS NVARCHAR) + 'AStatus'' = 1'
exec sp_executeSQL @sql
```

Example of a while loop

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max), @LinNum int

SELECT @LinNum = 1
WHILE(@LinNum <= 5)
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM table where ''Line' + CAST(@LinNum AS NVARCHAR) + 'AStatus'' = 1'
    exec sp_executeSQL @sql

    SELECT @LinNum = @LinNum + 1
END
```

Comment: SO change my query to nvarchar sorry use to c# and calling it string.

Comment: nvarchar is sql-servers "string", If you construct the statement as a string you can run it with `execute_sql`. It is often useful to put this as a stored procedure :)

Comment: If you don't mind me asking why the difference in standard and dynamic allowing you to use this?

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos dynamic will run a statement in a string so the advantage is you can construct the string how ever you need it (for example in a while loop) which can then be executed. standard SQL doesn't support fieldnames being constructed as it is "compiled" for lack of a better term at compile time and so can't be changed at runtime

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos noticed a few missed characters

Comment: Would you be able to look more in depth at it in chat? It's a bit more complicated in the full thing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50897/discussion-between-abstractchaos-and-kpt-khaos)